# MAMP Port Configuration

Tags: ios, apache, mamp, virtualhost

I'm running Mac Mavericks.

So I'm following the tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2 to implement a notification server.

I'm attempting to use MAMP PRO to follow the tutorial.

What I have done:

Folder Structure: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PushChatServer

Edited the etc/hosts file to add the following line:

```
     127.0.0.1       pushchat.local
```

Edited my https.conf file to add the following:

```
     Listen 44447
```

Uncommented the following line

```
     Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Edited my httpd-vhosts.conf file to add the following:

```
     NameVirtualHost *:44447

     <VirtualHost *:44447>
        DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PushChatServer/api"
        ServerName 192.168.78.199:44447
        #ServerName pushchat.local
        ServerAlias pushchat.local
        CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PushChatServer/log/apache_access.log" combined
        ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PushChatServer/log/apache_error.log"

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

        <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PushChatServer/api">
            Options Indexes All
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
                #Require all granted
        </Directory>

     </VirtualHost>
```

Pretty much this is everything as explained in the tutorial.

The only problem I have, is when I open the following URL http://pushchat.local:44447 in safari, it just hangs and does not load.

However, one silver lining is, if i enter http://pushchat.local/PushChatServer/api/index.php then this loads as it is expected.

I just don't understand why the first one does not work as it is explained in the tutorial. I've tried a number of things but nothing seems to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not a full solution, I thought I'd answer this in case anyone else has the same problem.

I noticed in the tutorial, they are using the free version of MAMP, so I uninstalled MAMP pro, and installed the free version, and guess what? it now works.

I'm not fully sure what the problem is with PRO and I'm sure there is some setting that needs changing, but I just can't work out what setting that would be. So for anyone in the same boat, following the same tutorial, this may be an option in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after several hours trying I end up with a pretty easy solution.
Please follow all your steps because they are all correct, you just need to remove/comment from the httpd.conf the line "#Listen 80".

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but, I resolved this issue following the steps of this page:

http://sawmac.com/mamp/virtual/

Mi file httpd.conf. work with this configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *

DocumentRoot "/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/NASA TV/MAMP"
ServerName localhost


DocumentRoot "/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/NASA TV/MAMP"
ServerName clientA.local
```

Only is neccesary to change the root of your computer.

Bye